# ng-view doesn't work correctly

Tags: angularjs-ng-route

I want to implement ngRoute in my angularjs project. But `<ng-view></ng-view>`  doesn't show anything. I read all other posts about this problem, but my problem is not resolved.

I define `$routeProvider` in app.js file as follows:

```
'use strict'
angular.module('confusionApp',  ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider)  {

$routeProvider

.when('/contactus', {   //  route   for the contactus page
       templateUrl :    'contactus.html',   controller      :   'ContactController'
})

.when('/menu',  {   //  route   for the menu    pag
       templateUrl :    'menu.html',    controller      :   'MenuController'
})

.when('/menu/:id',  {   //  route   for the dish    details pag
       templateUrl :    'dishdetail.html',  controller      :   'DishDetailController'
})

.otherwise('/contactus');
}]);
```

My controllers.js file includes the defenition of all my controllers:

```
 angular.module('confusionApp')

.controller('MenuController', ['$scope','menuFactory',function($scope,menuFactory){

    $scope.dishes = menuFactory.getDishes();
     //other codes which deleted for simplicity

}])

  .controller('dishDetailController',['$scope','$routeParams',
        'menuFactory', function($scope,$routeParams,menuFactory){

    var dish = menuFactory.getDish(parseInt($routeParams.id,10));
    this.dish = dish;
     //other codes which deleted for simplicity

}])

.controller('contactController',['$scope',function($scope){

       //some code here

}])

.controller('feedbackController',['$scope',function($scope){

       //some code here

}]);
```

And I defined factory in services.js file as follows:

```
  angular.module('confusionApp')

 .factory('menuFactory',function(){

    var menufac = {};

    var dishes=[{... some data ...}];

    menufac.getDishes = function(){
        return dishes;
    };

    menufac.getDish = function(index){
        return dishes[index];
    };

    return menufac;
  });
```

In my index.html page `<ng-view></ng-view>` doesn't show anything.for example when I click on menu tab, url become like this and menu data didn't reload:
`http://localhost/conFusion/#!/contactus#%2Fmenu`
my default page is contactus.
 Also I define scripts in index.html as follows and all the paths are true.

```
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/services.js"></script>
```

Comment: What does the console show?

Comment: @Anatoly nothing is shown in console.

Comment: What does the Network tab show for response when a request to any one of the template urls is made?